# Gremlin / Azure Cosmos DB: get all nodes with references to nodes with a certain property

Tags: gremlin

I have a Gremlin question.

Say I have three vertices:
`A -> (HasSuperior) X (Category = T)`
`B -> (HasSuperior) Y (Category = T)`
`C -> (HasSuperior) Z (Category = O)`

How can I write a query that provides all me vertices with an outgoing "HasSuperior" reference to vertices with Category property = T?

In this case, I would like to get vertex A and B as a result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved, I reversed it a bit.

```
g().has('category', 'O').inE().outV()
```

or

```
g().has('category', 'O').in()
```